# Configuring tools for specific agents Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, you have the "Global Tools Configuration" in the "Manage Jenkins" page. In there, you can configure all sort of tools - that is - configure their locations on the build agents and then in you Pipeline use the `tool` step to retrieve those paths.

I was wondering - why isn't there a way to configure these tools in a agent-specific manner, i.e., to configure paths in each Agent's page, and then in your Pipeline when you retreive a specific tool you'll get the path of that tool on that specific agent. Won't that be much more effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to overwrite locations for tool locations defined in the Global Tool Configuration.

The Global Tool Configurations has tool location usually with reference to the master node. So this location may or may not exists on the slave node. What we usually provide here is general location that is expected on all the machines in the nodes.

[image: Define Tools and Expected Location Global Levels]

The nodes can overwrite this location if they have tools on different location. That can be done by going in the nodes and configuring the nodes. Here is the snapshot for the same.
[image: Node Level Tool Location for the Tools defined in the Global Configuration]

So if you look at the snapshot you can see that there are two tools defined in the global tool configuration. GIT and JDK. And in the node level we can configure or overwrite the location for both GIT and JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I noticed that only if you configure a tool in the Global Tool Configuration, only then you'll be able to overwrite the location of it. Why not just let you configure tools on an agent-specific manner, regardless to the Global Tool configuration?

Comment: I dont know the exact answer but in case i have to guess i would say it is more convenient to have one global tool configuration then a separate node level. The jenkins that i manage is considerably small and have about 40 nodes. 30 of them are virtual containers with exact same image and exact same tool locations . Only 10 are physical machines that have some level of variations. So i guess for me to manage it is easier to define tool location in one place than in 40 different places. But this is just a guess from usage experience :)

Comment: I understand that. What I'm wondering is, say my Global Configuration doesn't specify a Gradle tool. Why isn't it possible to configure this only in a node configuration? But it's just a wonder :)

Comment: would it be possible to configure Tool Locations for node in jenkins pipeline?

Comment: For node specific tool configuration i found this `withEnv` pretty useful read about it https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables maybe this solves your problem as well.